# How to prepare list dynamically based on json attributes

Tags: java, json, list, dynamic

EDIT: Let us consider I have JSON attributes

***Input is:***

```
[{id:100,value:"eclispe",json_key:"ide"},{id:101,value:"java",json_key:"prog_lang"}]
```

***output excpected is:***

```
{"ide":[{"id":100,"name":"eclipse"}],"prog_lang":[{"id":101,"name":"java"}]}
```

this JSON above showing can be dynamic based on the attributes.

it can increase list

How I will find the list is having these many list in request.

How we will re-frame to JSON as per required.

Comment: I myself got the answer
Iterating the list and push json keys to Map
Map<String,List<Object>> obj= new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();

Comment: Could you try to explain what you need ? If I understand, based on the tags, you want to convert a `String` representing a JSON Array into a `List` in JAVA. What Library are you using to read the JSON ? The common are Jackson and Gson. Both have builders to generate `Bean` I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```js
var data = [
            {id:100,value:"eclispe",json_key:"ide"},
            {id:101,value:"java",json_key:"prog_lang"}
           ];

var newObj = {};
for (var i in data) {
  var jsonKeys = data[i].json_key;
  newObj[jsonKeys] = [];
  var objKeys = Object.keys(newObj);
  if(objKeys[i] == data[i].json_key) {
    data[i].name = data[i].value;
    delete data[i].json_key;
    delete data[i].value;
    newObj[objKeys[i]].push(data[i]);
  } 
}

document.getElementById("showJson").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

```html
<div id="showJson"></div>
```